# Interpolate macro matcher into a string literal

Tags: rust

This snippet prints `$i`, but I would like it to print `foo`. I've tried a few variations on this theme which didn't work, nor was I able to find anything in the documentation about this behavior. Is there syntax to make this possible?

```
macro_rules! print_ident {
    ($i:ident) => {
        println!("$i");  
    };
}

fn main() {
    print_ident!(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html).

```
macro_rules! print_ident {
    ($i:ident) => {
        println!(stringify!($i));  
    };
}

fn main() {
    print_ident!(foo);
}
```